# How to pass a state's value into props in React class component

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-map-react

I am getting geocode locations into the latt,lngg variables through axios and setState , i want to use this variables inside google-map-react package center How can i pass these state values into props .

Rest API

```js
then(res => {
  console.log(res.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
  console.log(res.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng);
  // console.log(res.data[0]);

  this.setState({latt:res.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat})
  this.setState({lngg:res.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng})
})

static defaultProps = {
  center: {
    lat: 32,
    lng: 56
  },
  zoom: 5.7
};

<GoogleMapReact bootstrapURLKeys={{ key:API-KEY}} defaultCenter={this.props.center} defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}>
```

Answer (score 0):

For referencing state values, you'd use `this.state.center` and `this.state.zoom` rather than `this.props.` which is for the props of the current component.